# exist-db restxq trigger : Services deleted but still active

Tags: rest, exist-db, xquery-3.0, restxq

I have issues with the RESTXQ implementation in exist-db.
I think it might be the RestXQTrigger which is not working correctly.

The problem: I deleted (via the Dashboard) a collection including RESTXQ services inside several `.xqm` files. However, the services are not unregistered and are still available, even after restarting eXist.

Is there any way to force this unregistring, I mean other than recreate the previous collections/files and delete each `.xqm` files one by one (this way, the trigger seems to work) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stop the database, and manually remove the registry file `$EXIST_HOME/webapp/WEBINF/data/restxq.registry`

Comment: I was looking for this for soooooo long !!! Thank you !! Can't find this anywhere in the documentation, is it ?

Comment: it is documented, but i had to digg deep. https://www.google.nl/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=restxq+registry&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=wlSUVN2-AdeCUNb0gcgC#rls=en&q=restxq+restxq.registry showed that it is at least mentioned in the just released 'eXist' book by AdamR and ErikS

Comment: Nope, it does not seem to be documented in the eXist-db documentation, sorry.

Comment: Ok. I already bought the adam's book :-D, but don't have it yet. I still have a question, would you consider RestXQ as fully operationnal or still in beta-mode ? Because we're considering using it in production mode.

Comment: I'd say it is production worthy. It has been quite well tested and it is actively maintained.

Answer (score 4):

RESTXQ in eXist at the moment only implements the Document Trigger events and not the Collection Trigger events. This is just a limitation which needs to be resolved when there is time to implement it.

There is an XQuery module provided with eXist in the namespace: `http://exquery.org/ns/restxq/exist`. The functions in this module enable you to manually manipulate the RESTXQ Registry. You can enable it in `$EXIST_HOME/conf.xml`. If you then restart eXist and re-build the function documentation you should be able to see the documentation in the function browser app for these functions. In particular you most likely want the functions:

`exrest:deregister-module(xs:anyURI("/db/my-module.xqm"))` and `exrest:register-module(xs:anyURI("/db/my-module.xqm"))`.

There are also functions for registering and deregistering individual functions from a module, which are called `register-resource-function` and `deregister-resource-function` they are similar to above but take a second argument which is a function signature (as a xs:string) in the form of *qname#arity* e.g. `"fn:substring#2"`

Comment: Thanks for the precisions ! This documentation was welcome :-)
 This way, I feel more comfortable to use RESTXQ in our production plateform. Thanks again.

Comment: Apart from the eXist O'Reilly book, the documentation for RESTXQ is quite lacking, the next best source is probably http://www.adamretter.org.uk/presentations.xml#xmlprague12. However, eXist is an Open Source project, and I would welcome a pull-request that adds some documentation for RESTXQ, see: https://github.com/exist-db/documentation